# How to change the icon color on the desktop using any programming language?

Tags: windows, icons

I want to change the icon color on the desktop using any programming language. 
For example, Whatsapp has the icon color of green, I want to change it to a blue color using any programming language. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: kumar you should be a bit more specific: which environment are you referring to (Windows, Android, IOS, etc)?

Comment: I am asking about Windows 10 operating system